# in dropdown selected index changed i want to create Dynamic empty textbox inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create dynamic textbox inside gridview when dropdown selected index changed in every row we create 5 dynamic textbox. when i use some code from google search to create dynamic textbox code inside rowdatabound or ondatabound  it doesn't fire Can anyone help me Thanx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClassUnits" runat="server" class="textusername"
    Style="width: 100%;" ValidationGroup="ClassesRequired"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClassUnits_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">

    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>

    <asp:ListItem Text="Unit-1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>

    <asp:ListItem Text="SelectAll" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:GridView ID="GridViewclass" runat="server"
    OnRowDataBound="GridViewclass_RowDataBound"
    OnDataBound="GridViewclass_DataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
    HeaderStyle- BackColor="#174A63" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="white"
    AllowPaging="true" Font- Size="14px" Style="margin-left: 16%;"
    PageSize="15" Width="300px">

    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="selectedRowStyle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you show what's inside the `ddlClassUnits_SelectedIndexChanged` method? But you could always add an `ItemTemplate` to the GridView with the TextBoxes and show/hide the entire column based on the DropDownList.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should steer away from the idea of creating "textboxes" - what you need to do is modify the underlying DataSource to include the desired amount of new columns and set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` to be able to simply refresh your GridView.

This will give you an editable Grid without the hassle of creating single controls by hand.

Yet another option would be to determine the max. amount of columns beforehand and just **show** more columns when the selection changes (`AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in that case).

---

I played around a little and can give you the basic idea - however I see another big problem rising when you want to save your data ... but this cannot be answered without knowing more about your task.

**Layout**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClassUnits" 
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClassUnits_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  AutoPostBack="true"
                  runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Unit-1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="SelectAll" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:GridView ID="ClassGrid"
              runat="server"
              AutoGenerateColumns="false"
              EditIndex="0">
</asp:GridView>
```

*I did set the `EditIndex="0"` so you immediately see the TextBoxes.*

**Code**

```
protected void ddlClassUnits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get a dummy data source with 5 columns
    DataTable dt = this.GetData(5);

    // assign it as GridView data source
    this.GridViewclass.DataSource = dt;

    // create bound columns for your GridView
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        BoundField field = new BoundField();
        field.DataField = col.ColumnName;
        field.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
        this.GridViewclass.Columns.Add(field);
    }

    this.GridViewclass.DataBind();
}

// creates a DataTable as datasource for your GridView with as many columns as you like
private DataTable GetData(int cols)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Class");

    // auto-generate columns
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add($"col{i}", typeof(string));
    }

    // create an empty row just so you see something
    var dr = dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    return dt;
}
```

Please note that this doesn't do anything sensible - it just shows how you can add columns dynamically that give you TextBoxes when a new row is added or an existing row is set to edit mode.

Comment: i want to create it from code behind so i use AutoGenerateColumns="False". i m new in this field so pleaze help to create it. Thanks

Comment: If you can update your post to show what kind of data is bound to your GridView, I can update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: empty textbox we created in every column when textboxt is create then user will fill that textbox and save it from

Comment: Hey buddy are u there?

Comment: Did my sample convince you that what you need is possible without creating textboxes?